# ErrorStdOut in AutoIt

Tags: autoit

This is my code:

```
Run("C:\Program Files\teraterm\ttermpro.exe",@SW_MAXIMIZE)
Sleep("3000")
Send("!{o}")
Sleep(500)
Send("m")
Sleep("1000")
Send("E:\To_PV\scripts\boot.ttl")
send("{ENTER}")
```

I just want to open the application and then open a file in it. But it's not opening, and it is typing the file path in the editor itself. This is what I got in the message box:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "D:\PV\macro\macro.au3"
```

I am using AutoIt (latest version) on Windows XP.

Comment: This output is just the standard output when the program is running. It should terminate with `>Exit code: 0   Time: 4.505` or something like this in your case. Try to `ConsoleWrite(@error & @CR)` after your *Run*-command.

Comment: I tried this funtion and got the same message on the first line.  On second line I got ``1`` and on third line I got ``Exit code: 0 Time: 4.505``.  Still the application is not opening

Comment: That means, the [`Run(...)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) function is not called properly. So you have to check for your parameters being correct. As stated in your answer below, the space in the file path is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters for [`Run()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) are wrong. The 2nd parameter must be the working directory or an empty string:

```
Run("C:\Program Files\teraterm\ttermpro.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Comment: I checked it in window's 7, it is working but in XP, it's not working, showing the same message

Comment: I tried to open other application using the Run(), for some it was working well and for others it was not.

Comment: That's weird. I ran TeraTerm this way on XP Professional, Vista Business and 7 Ultimate without a problem. Are you absolutely sure you had the correct syntax? Not as in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have found the solution. Actually I was using Windows XP Service Pack 2. It seems that Run() doesn't work properly in Windows XP Service Pack 2. This problem can be resolved by adding single apostrophe at the starting and ending point of the file path string. For example,

if the path of the application is:

```
"C:\Program Files\myprogram\myprogram.exe"
```

all you need to do is to add single inverted comma to the path string. So it would look like:

```
'"C:\Program Files\myprogram\myprogram.exe"'
```

It doesn't matter whether you use the following syntax:

```
Run('"C:\Program Files\teraterm\ttermpro.exe"', "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

or simply:

```
Run('"C:\Program Files\teraterm\ttermpro.exe"')
```

Both would work well.

Comment: I cannot see a difference in your last two example code lines... What's yout point there? And as @Matt stated, the problem is with the space in the path name. You could use `Run(@ProgramFilesDir & "\teraterm\ttermpro.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)` instead to omit this problem...

Comment: Ok... and with `Run('"' & @ProgramFilesDir & '\teraterm\ttermpro.exe"', "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)`? This should work? If `@ProgramFilesDir` evaluates to *C:\Program Files*